# Can I put "it's" before "no wonder" when I make a kind of conclusion?

Tags: phrase-choice

Can I put "it's" before "no wonder" when I make a kind of conclusion (having presented some facts about why my conclusion shouldn't be surprising)? Or it will sound awkward?:

> James studied karate in the second grade and judo in the third grade.
>   Besides he is very much into weightlifting and boxing. So, **it's no
>   wonder** that he is considered the strongest boy in this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That phrase is used in conversation to point out something obvious, especially when it has been overlooked, or when the interlocutor had been unaware of it.

> Your little boy won't go near the sliding board during recess.
>   -- He fell off a sliding board last year and broke his wrist.
>   Ah, no wonder he wants to have nothing to do with it.

Or

> The dog's water bowl has been empty all day. You forgot to fill it this morning. It's no wonder she's so thirsty.